# traits class, namespace and forward declaration

Tags: c++, design-patterns, coding-style, api-design, generic-programming

I am currently having trouble using namespaces with traits classes. Here is my tentative code structure:

```
namespace project {

namespace internal {
template<typename T> struct traits;

} // internal

namespace moduleA {

namespace internal {

class AImpl {

using some_typeA = traits<A>::some_type;
using some_typeAImpl = traits<AImpl>::some_type;
// where to put the traits specialization?? How the forward declaration could be done?

};

} // internal

class A {

A(): imp(new internal::AImpl()) {}
private:
    internal::AImpl* imp;
};

} // moduleA

} // project
```

Here are my questions and I am looking for suggestions to make this code better follow the established conventions and best practices:

1. I am defining two internal namespaces, `::project::internal` and `::project::moduleA::internal`, is this a bad practice? My concern on this is that with two levels it might be easier for user to browse the documentation from doxygen, as all the moduleA related stuff, both moduleA::internal and not, are grouped together.
2. Because `moduleA::internal::AImpl` depends on the traits class of itself `traits<AImpl>`, and my traits templates resides in `::project::internal`, so I have to either (1) define a traits template in `moduleA::internal` and specialize it; (2) define the traits specialization in `::project::internal`. For this, I'll need forward-declare AImpl. How exactly should it be done for each of the case (1) or (2)? Does that mean I have to write code like this:

```
namespace project {
namespace moduleA {class A;}
namespace internal {
template<>
struct traits<module::A> {};
}
namespace moduleA {
... // more code
}
}
```

It looks like I am making too much use of `namespace {}` clauses.

3. Similar to 2, `module::internal::AImpl` depends on `traits<A>`, again I need to forward declare A, so the same problem.

I'd greatly appreciate you help on this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using class templates for traits in C++11 you can use function declarations (no definition is necessary). Functions can be found using [argument-dependent name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), so that you can specialise traits for your class in the same namespace where your class is declared.

This completely removes the nuisance of having to close the namespace of your class, open the traits namespace, specialise the trait for your class using its fully qualified name, close the traits namespace, re-open the namespace of your class. And also removes the need to include the declaration of the primary template.

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> struct Type {};

template<class T>
void trait_of(Type<T>); // Generic trait version.

namespace N {
struct A;
int trait_of(Type<A>); // Trait specialisation for A.
} // N

int main() {
    using trait_of_a = decltype(trait_of(Type<N::A>{})); // trait_of is found using ADL.
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, trait_of_a>::value, "");
}
```

The return type of the trait function can be a container of more types, e.g.:

```
template<class T>
void more_traits(Type<T>); // Generic trait version. Must be specialized.

namespace N {
struct MoreTraitsOfA {
    using type_X = ...;
    using type_Y = ...;
};
MoreTraitsOfA more_traits(Type<A>); // Trait specialisation for A.
} // N

using MoreTraits = decltype(more_traits(Type<N::A>{})); 
using type_X = MoreTraits::type_X;
using type_Y = MoreTraits::type_Y;
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know I can do this. It seems very convenient if a traits class contains only a few member types. To my situation, I can have `std::string key_type(A);` and `int value_type(A)` and use `decltype(value_type(declval(A)))` to get the type to use. Could you elaborate why I need the `Type` template? And why I am not seeing this pattern widely in-use elsewhere?

Comment: @JerryMa If you use `std::declval<A>()` then the trait function must accept it as `A const&` and hence that function would also accept classes derived from `A`, which may or may not be desirable. `Type<A>` doesn't match derived classes of `A`. `Type` is essentially `boost::type` or Alexandrescu's `Type2Type`, its main purpose is to discriminate function overloads, just like what we do here. It allows to pass a type as a function argument without having to construct a value of that type somehow, disables (unexpected) conversions, and most conveniently, it doesn't preclude ADL.

Comment: Love it. Could you add a little note about `constexpr` though, please. I have the nagging feeling that it (ADL) will fail if one tries to make all traits (and `trait_of`) `constexpr`. Then again, it's probably not needed if one only uses types as in the second example.

Comment: @non-user38741 Why would `constexpr` make ADL fail?

Comment: It was just a suspicion because of limited knowledge about what's really happening in the compiler. Phases... Maybe I once heard something, somewhere...  But it's not an issue. In fact I have successfully implemented your pattern with everything `constexpr` just now.

Comment: @non-user38741 Also, `constexpr` on the trait functions makes no difference because the functions are never called. `decltype` gives the type that the function would return if it were callled, without actually calling the function.